# variable 't' is assigned a value but never used in vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js

help me to solve these this error:
i am importing a template in vue.js but I am getting so many errors such as:

```
't' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
  1068:33  error  'calendarEvents' is not defined             no-undef
  1119:80  error  'index' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
  1119:87  error  'element' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
  1357:35  error  'Odometer' is not defined                   no-undef
  1391:45  error  'Instafeed' is not defined                  no-undef
  1410:45  error  'Instafeed' is not defined                  no-undef
  1553:17  error  't' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
  1576:25  error  '$this' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  1628:41  error  'slider' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
  1629:29  error  'imagesLoaded' is not defined               no-undef
  2125:17  error  't' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
  2152:17  error  't' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
  2178:4   error  'jQuery' is not defined                     no-undef
```

````
var t = setTimeout(function() {
                theme.header.TM_fullscreenMenu();
                theme.header.TM_sidePanelReveal();
                theme.header.TM_scroolToTopOnClick();
                theme.header.TM_scrollToFixed();
                theme.header.TM_sticky();
                theme.header.TM_topnavAnimate();
                theme.header.TM_scrolltoTarget();
                theme.header.TM_navLocalScorll();
                theme.header.TM_menuCollapseOnClick();
                theme.header.TM_homeParallaxFadeEffect();
                theme.header.TM_topsearch_toggle();
            }, 0);

        },```

The error is : 't' is assigned a value but never used.

could anyone help me to get out of such errors?
````

Comment: you cant simply copy and paste your jquery based template code into vue and expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning from ESLint. The code is perfectly valid syntax-wise.

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns an integer that identifies the timeout if you want to clear it with [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout).

ESLint is warning you that you are creating but not using the `t` variable. If you have no use of the timeout identifier, just remove the `t` variable and don't assign the `setTimeout`'s return value.